# Do i have to reinstall gapps when flashing an rom update

Tags: custom-roms

So I'm currently running chroma rom on my nexus 5 and I wanted to know if I have to reinstall the gapps file when I flash it. I would also like to know if I have to also reinstall gapps when flashing a new rom. Help will be Really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the ROM you are installing. Most of the ROMs don't come with gapps integrated. So you have to install the correct version of gapps that matched android version and system of your android device. A fresh install of any new ROM always requires you to have gapps if you need them. Re-installs( dirty flashing) ROMs doesn't require re-install of gapps.

Comment: So when I update my rom I don't have to reinstall gapps? And thanks for the reply